# Redirect from index to another route and force model()

Tags: ember.js

I'd like to forward the user to `/articles` when he arrives at `/`. Unfortunately, `/articles`'s `model()`-function will not be executed because it's not a page refresh:

```
App.IndexRoute = Em.Route.extend
    redirect: ->
        @transitionTo "articles"
```

What's the Ember-way to achieve this?

Comment: Adding it to setupController wont help ?

Comment: Is there a more straightforward solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can't really tell the rest of your setup, but this is how I achieve it

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  adapter: DS.FixtureAdapter
});

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('articles', function() {
    this.resource('article', {path: ':article_id'});
  });
});

App.Article = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string')
});

App.Article.FIXTURES = [{
  id: 1,
  title: 'blah'
}, {
  id: 2,
  title: 'more blah'
}];

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  redirect: function() {
   this.transitionTo('articles'); 
  }
});

App.ArticlesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.Article.find();
  }
});
```

working example:
http://jsbin.com/imidiq/2/

Comment: Thanks a lot, exactly what I needed. I wasn't aware that it's possible to create sub-resources with `{ path: ":article_id" }`